# Why these two sectors are equal

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We consider the sector $$\Sigma(\varphi)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}: |\arg(\lambda)|<\arcsin(1/c)\}.$$
Why this sector equals the set $$\bigcup_{\lambda_0>0}\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} : |\lambda-\lambda_0|<\lambda_0/c\}$$ where $c>0$.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I tried to make a representation, but i don't know how arcsin disappears in the second set!

Comment: I'd suggest starting with a particular value of $c$ and try to work it out in that case. If you take $c = \sqrt 2$ the region $\Sigma(\varphi)$ is bounded by the lines $y = \pm x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $c$ must be greater than $1$ and
$$ \arcsin\bigg(\frac1c\bigg)=\arctan\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}\bigg). $$
Set $\lambda=x+yi$ ($x,y$ are real). Using
$$ \arg(\lambda)=\arctan\left(\frac yx\right) $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\Sigma(\varphi)&=&\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}: |\arg(\lambda)|<\arcsin(1/c)\}\\
&=&\{x+yi: \left|\arctan\left(\frac yx\right)\right|<\arctan\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}\bigg),x>0\}\\
&=&\{x+yi: |y|<\frac{x}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}\}\\
\end{eqnarray}
This means that the geometric meaning of the sector $\Sigma(\varphi)$ is the inside of the region between $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}x$ and $y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}x$ for $x>0$.
Also
\begin{eqnarray}
A&=:&\bigcup_{\lambda_0>0}\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} : |\lambda-\lambda_0|<\lambda_0/c\}\\
&=&\bigcup_{\lambda_0>0}\{x+yi : (x-\lambda_0)^2+y^2<\lambda_0^2/c^2\}
\end{eqnarray}
and then the geometric meaning of $A$ is the union of the open disks centering at $(\lambda_0,0)$ with radius $\lambda_0/c$ for $\lambda_0>0$.

It is easy to see that each open disk centering at $(\lambda_0,0)$ with radius $\lambda_0/c$ for $\lambda_0>0$ is inside of $\Sigma(\varphi)$, which means $A\subset \Sigma(\varphi)$. On the other hand, let $\lambda=x_0+y_0i\in \Sigma(\varphi)$. Clearly $x_0,y_0>0$. Define
$$ \lambda_0=x_0+\frac{y_0}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}. $$
One can check easily that $\lambda=x+yi\in A$, which mean $\Sigma(\varphi)\subset A$. Thus
$$ \Sigma(\varphi) =A. $$

Comment: What if $0<c\leq1$, what can we do in this case ?

Comment: The domain of $\arcsin x$ is $[-1,1]$. If $c=1$, the sector would be the right half plane. If $c\in(0,1)$, $\arcsin(1/c)$ is meaningless.

Comment: Why $\lambda\in A$ ? we have $|\lambda-\lambda_0|=\frac{y_0}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}c$

Comment: You can use geometry to get it.